# Ignite UI for Angular (igx-grid ) how to block filtering and sorting

Tags: angular7, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

Ignite UI for Angular `igx-grid` how to block filtering and sorting, I want to block filtering and sorting while updating row data and while adding New entry. Once I save again in can filter and sort data.

1. I am adding new entry in same grid but getting problem

   - Insert new row getting sorted by inserted characters alphabetically
2. and same for updating entry entry in same grid but getting problem

   - Insert new row getting sorted by inserted characters alphabetically
     suppose type z in textbook it get sorted to last row of grid

Answer (score 1):

All of the data transformation features in the igx-grid act as standard Angular pipes. They are chained one after another on the grid data binding, and upon data change, they are triggered and applied, as you would expect in a regular Angular change detection lifecycle.

Essentially, your question is whether this lifecycle can be broken and the answer is that if it's broken, then that would require all of those pipe triggers to be transferred to a manual mode, essentially turning off the Angular change detection and triggered manually by the application utilizing the component.